# modifying Makefile for silverfrost FTN95 ( Windows)

Tags: makefile, fortran

[Compiling error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omcLg.png)

I am quite new to Fortran coding.
Currently, I have a makefile which has been previously used by original authors to compile the Fortran codes in Linux. However, I cannot understand what needs to be changed in the previous makefile to run it in Windows-based compiler Silverfrost FTN95.
While trying to compile in FTN95 I encountered the following error:

> C:\Users\Geo-TGS\Documents\landslidemodel\src\TRIGRS>MAKE TPX
>
> mpif90 -w -O3 -w -O3 -c ssizgrd.f95
>
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, mpif90 -w -O3 -w -O3 -c ssizgrd.f95, ...) failed.
>
> make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> makefile:59: recipe for target `ssizgrd.o' failed
>
> MAKE: *** [ssizgrd.o] Error 2
>
> C:\Users\Geo-TGS\Documents\landslidemodel\src\TRIGRS>make trg
>
> mpif90 -w -O3 -w -O3 -c grids.f95
>
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, mpif90 -w -O3 -w -O3 -c grids.f95, ...) failed.
>
> make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> makefile:59: recipe for target `grids.o' failed
>
> make: *** [grids.o] Error 2

Below is the Makefile code:

```
TRG = trg

PRG = prg

TPX = tpx

OBJT90 = trigrs.o flux.o prpijz.o svxmdv.o svijz.o dzero_brac.o

OBJT95 = grids.o input_vars.o model_vars.o dsimps.o input_file_defs.o iverson.o pstpi.o satfin.o savage.o steady.o trini.o unsinf.o ivestp.o pstpf.o rnoff.o satinf.o smallt.o svgstp.o unsfin.o unsth.o ssizgrd.o svlist.o

OBJT77 = calerf.o dbsct.o derfc.o irdgrd.o irdswm.o isvgrd.o roots.o srdgrd.o srdswm.o ssvgrd.o

OBJP90 = trigrs_p.o partial_p.o flux.o flux_p.o prpijz.o svxmdv.o svijz.o dzero_brac.o srdgrd_p.o irdgrd_p.o

OBJP95 = modules_p.o grids.o input_vars.o model_vars.o dsimps.o input_file_defs.o iverson.o pstpi.o pstpi_p.o satfin.o satfin_p.o savage.o steady.o trini.o trini_p.o unsinf.o unsinf_p.o ivestp.o ivestp_p.o pstpf.o pstpf_p.o rnoff.o satinf.o satinf_p.o smallt.o svgstp.o svgstp_p.o unsfin.o unsfin_p.o unsth.o unsth_p.o ssizgrd.o ssizgrd_p.o svlist.o rnoff_p.o steady_p.o

OBJP77 = calerf.o dbsct.o derfc.o irdgrd.o irdswm.o irdswm_p.o isvgrd.o roots.o srdgrd.o srdswm.o srdswm_p.o ssvgrd.o

OBJX90 = tpindx.o nxtcel.o

OBJX95 = ssizgrd.o

OBJX77 = isvgrd.o mpfldr.o rdflodir.o sindex.o slofac.o srdgrd1.o

LIBS =

CC = gcc -O3

CCFLAGS = -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm

FC = ftn95 -w -O3 


FFLAGS =

F90 = f95 -w -O3

MPIF90 = mpif90 -w -O3

F90FLAGS = -w -O3

LDFLAGS = -w -O3

all: $(TRG) $(PRG)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------

$(TRG): $(OBJT95) $(OBJT90) $(OBJT77) 

    $(F90) $(CCLIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJT95) $(OBJT90) $(OBJT77) $(CCFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(PRG): $(OBJP95) $(OBJP90) $(OBJP77) 

    $(MPIF90) $(CCLIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJP95) $(OBJP90) $(OBJP77) 
$(CCFLAGS) $(LIBS)


$(TPX): $(OBJX95) $(OBJX90) $(OBJX77)

    $(F90) $(CCLIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJX95) $(OBJX90) $(OBJX77) $(CCFLAGS) $(LIBS)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
clean:
    rm -f $(TRG) $(TPX) $(PRG)
    rm -rf $(OBJT95) $(OBJT90) $(OBJT77) $(OBJP95) $(OBJP90) $(OBJP77)
    rm -rf $(OBJX95) $(OBJX90) $(OBJX77)
    rm -rf *.mod *.exe *.stackdump

.SUFFIXES: $(SUFFIXES) .f90 .f .c .f95

.f90.o:

    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<

.f.o:

    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<

.c.o:

    $(CC) $(CCINCLUDE) -c -w $<

.f95.o:

    $(MPIF90) $(F90FLAGS) -c $<
```

What changes need to be made for the code to compile?

Comment: Is the command mpif90 in your path ?

Comment: Where is the Makefile located? Where are the source files located? For example files `ssizgrd.f95` and `grids.f95`.

Comment: @VladimirF: The makefile and source files are located in the same folder. (e.g: C:\Users\Geo-TGS\Documents\landslidemodel\src\TRIGRS)

Comment: @albert:  I installed microsoft mpi v9 and have set the path in environment variables. The mpi.f90 file exists in a folder C:\Program files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include

Comment: mpi.f90, I hope a typo as this is a source file and not an executable (mpif90.bat, mpif90.exe or mpif90.cmd). What happens when in a command window you type mpif90 ?what gives the command: where mpif90 ?